# Font problem in PDF export after reporting services migration

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

Our reporting services migrated from SSRS 2005 to SSRS 2016. In one specific report, a particular field of looks different on the pdf export. The font that's specified in the report rdl file for that specific field was internally designed a long time ago. We thought the problem had to do with it not being installed in the new server and we proceeded to installing it. After the installation, the result looked different (meaning that the recently installed font was being used) but still very different from the pdf export on the original server. Keep in mind that the rdl files for the report are exactly the same.

My questions is: is it possible to configure some kind of font mapping at server level, so it will replace one font for other, when exporting to pdf?

Any other ideas that explain why the same rdl file looks different in the two SSRS servers when exported to PDF?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you examine the properties inside of Adobe reader you can see what fonts are being used as one check

Comment: we have also faced a similar issue with local RDLC report and in our case font was not installed on the server. once we have installed it's not picked the font but after server restart installed font was picked up and PDF generated as expected except see some spacing issue on report noticed.  You can verify which fonts used in PDF using adobe acrobat reader, open the PDF, properties, font tab.